# How to convert a Twig array into JavaScript array

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig, octobercms

I have a Twig array and I want to send it to JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var packages = {{packages}}
</script>
```

> Error! Array to String Conversion.

How should I do that?

Comment: can u elaborate more... Your question is not clear

Comment: thanx @DarkBee it is working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use `json_encode` twig filter to pass your arrays into javascript:

**Twig**

```
{% set packages = [1, 2, 3, 4] %}

<script>
    var packages = {{ packages|json_encode }}
</script>
```

**Output**

```
<script>
    var packages = [1,2,3,4]
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work with Twig v2.13.1, use @Stanley85 's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63391632/6127393

Answer (score 31):

I have an array from twig named filters, this single line did the job

```
const filters = JSON.parse('{{ filters | json_encode | raw }}');
```

Comment: I had to use backtick (`) instead of single quotes in the function param because one of the JSON values had a single-quote in it (apostrophe essentially).

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers didn't work for me. Specifically, it failed when the original array contained any string containing newlines (`\n`).

This is what worked for me:

```
let jsArray = JSON.parse('{{ twig_array|json_encode|e("js") }}');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//javascript
const myArray = JSON.parse('{{ packages[0] }}');
```

Or this:

```
//javascript
const myArray = {{ packages[0] }};
```